# How to reverse a git repository

Tags: git

There is a complete source code of a simple app, and a need to create teaching material based on it. So, I was thinking, init a git repository from complete sources, then start simplifying and removing parts in reverse order, and commit each subsequently simpler working version, until only a "Hello, World!" remains.

Question: how to reverse commits in a git repository, preserving commit messages etc, so that it looks like it was originally committed in this order?

It is acceptable to use any other VCS to do the simplifying part, as long as final result is a git repo.

Comment: Why do you want to actually change history for that? You can just walk over commits backwards

Comment: I don't think git has this feature right now. You could try to write a shell script for that.

Comment: @NevikRehnel In a teaching situation, any deviation from "normal", whether teacher explains it or glosses over it, distracts both the teacher and the students, and should generally be avoided, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a script, "git-reverse.sh," that completely reverses all branches of a git repo.

It uses the a combination of `git log --pretty="%T"` to extract the tree hashes, and `git commit-tree` to make new commit objects against the original tree objects (the files), but with the parent edges reversed.

It seems to get stuck with some repos. I don't know why.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/gsylvie/git-reverse.sh

**Example Usage**

```
git clone --mirror [git-clone-url]
cd [repo.git]
./git-reverse.sh
git log --all --date-order --graph --decorate
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./git-reverse.sh 
be0923ece8f73281e5e54906c29debb852894b92 - Reversed 1 of 360 (0%)
061bca59b29e75becbde66d2e510fc2b4059ccb2 - Reversed 2 of 360 (0%)
6a19039e05e3a0186187d0a6943634e8499b5a65 - Reversed 3 of 360 (0%)
7afe25e8caf93eb7107471a1bd078d4adc3f6999 - Reversed 4 of 360 (1%)
8b556f6fe97c5357c2328467a5ba01b77931ff82 - Reversed 5 of 360 (1%)
71fd0883975154f48059ca929db8ccb659c5049a - Reversed 6 of 360 (1%)
[etc...]
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 199 and 159 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

*********************************************
| Git repo successfully reversed!!! :-) (-: |
*********************************************
To push the reversed repo:
  rm .git/packed-refs
  rm -rf .git/refs/remotes
  git push --mirror [new-git-clone-url]  

WARNING:
========
Pushing a reversed git repo is a profoundly destructive and confusing operation.

You have a full 'git clone --mirror' backup stored somewhere safe, right?
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `git format-patch` to get patches into files, sort them anti-chronologicaly (numbered filenames, then `sort -r`) and apply as new commits to new empty repository using `git apply --reverse`. Then I would use interactive rebase (`-i`) to fix details and commit messages.

Anyway, git is good tool for this becouse you can easily manipulate with history, but it will require some work.

**EDIT:**

When I looked at this later, I've got a better idea how to do this. It does not change basic principle, only implementation:

I expect, that you have repository with some history in master branch. So easiest way to *mirror* commits over current HEAD is this:

```
git checkout -b mirror
git log --format=%H | xargs -n 1 git revert
```

Now you have old history in master branch and new commits between master and mirror are reversed commits from master. Just like looking into mirror. I guess you will want to cut away old history and edit commit messages, so have fun with `git rebase -i`.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably what will be done, more or less. I'll accept your answer soon(ish), unless someone steps up and actually writes the script ;)

Comment: Thanks! Looks much better than the shell `for` loop thing I had in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

If number of commits in the repository is limited (I think it is the case as you are making a teaching material), I think you may simply perform cherry pick in reverse order manually.

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
                    ^HEAD
```

Assume A is the very first commit which is empty, while B is the full set of file, and C D E is gradually removal of files, I think you can start of by another branch at A

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
^NewHead            ^HEAD
```

and cherry pick E, D, C, B to New Head:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
 ^                  ^HEAD
  \- E' <- D' <- C' <- B'
                       ^NewHead
```

Of course, if there are really lots of commits, exporting patches and use script to manipulate them before importing (as suggested by other answer) may be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand why do you need to change commits. You could just checkout corresponding versions in any order. I.e. `git checkout master~1`, show, `git checkout master~2`, show, an so on.

If you really do need it to have you your history, then try to use `revert` which replays history back. E.g. `git revert HEAD~5..HEAD` will revert last 5 commits in reverse order. However, it generates commit messages to say that it is `Revert "old commit message"`. But you could make a script to amend the messages.

Comment: Well, when looking at history at something like github, or just `git log`, it should look "normal". Also, commits do not need to be changed, exactly. A repository with commits in desired order needs to be produced. So, as explained in other answers, it'll probably be a simple shell script exporting the last source, initing new repo from it, then reverse-applying the commit diffs from other repo in reverse order. I was just asking if there was a ready-made way of doing this, without hacking together a custom shell script.

Comment: You could do it with git revert and rebase.. The only problem that `revert` produces special commit messages... not sure how easy to deal with it.